# Vertical Fourier and Laplace "club" symbols

Tags: symbols, fourier

The [`trfsigns`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/trfsigns) package provides macros for transformation signs, eg: `\fourier` and `\laplace`.

[image]

I need a vertical version of those symbols.

Comment: These symbols (horizontal or vertical) are also part of the [Comprehensive LaTeX Symbol List](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf) (Table 72, p 31, amongst others, possibly). For me this is a duplicate of [How to look up a symbol or identify a math symbol or character?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14/5764)

Comment: Didn't knew about the symbols from the cited table. However, they are pretty small compared to those from the trfsigns package.

Comment: It already exists as a Metafont font in the `trsym` package. There it's a binary relation symbol.

Comment: @SimonD.Seim: Pretty small can be resized using [`graphicx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx) and put in a macro as a `\mathrel`, if needed.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,12pt]{report}

\usepackage{trfsigns} % Transformation Symbol o---o \laplace and \Laplace

\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}

\newcommand{\vlaplace}[1][]{\mbox{\setlength{\unitlength}{0.1em}%
                            \begin{picture}(10,20)%
                              \put(3,2){\circle{4}}%
                              \put(3,4){\line(0,1){12}}%
                              \put(3,18){\circle*{4}}%
                              \put(10,7){#1}
                            \end{picture}%
                           }%
                     }%

\newcommand{\vLaplace}[1][]{\mbox{\setlength{\unitlength}{0.1em}%
                            \begin{picture}(10,20)%
                              \put(3,2){\circle*{4}}%
                              \put(3,4){\line(0,1){12}}%
                              \put(3,18){\circle{4}}%
                              \put(10,7){#1}
                            \end{picture}%
                           }%
                     }%                     

\begin{document}

\[ s(t) = stuff \]
\[\vlaplace\]
\[ S(f) = otherstuff \]
\[\vLaplace[Used Rule No. 1 from Table No. 7] \]
\[ s(t) = again \]

\end{document}
```

Comment: I think, you did this the other way around. The black dot should be on the Laplace side